# Maven and Vaadin plugin could not find any themes

Tags: maven, vaadin

Where do I set vaadin.theme?

--- vaadin-maven-plugin:7.5.7:update-theme (default-cli) @ YT-100_ATU_Controller ---

Vaadin plugin could not find any themes.

No themes found. Use the parameter "vaadin.theme" to explicitly select a theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
<vaadin.theme>themename</vaadin.theme>
```

that should make it work

Comment: Where should one add this?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to user5377106's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33003435/2641361):

> Add
>
> `<vaadin.theme>themename</vaadin.theme>`
>
> that should make it work

Open your maven's pom.xml and find the section properties. It contains for example the Vaadin version. You need to add `<vaadin.theme>themename</vaadin.theme>` to this section. It'll look kind of like this:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <vaadin.version>7.6.2</vaadin.version>
    <vaadin.theme>MyTheme</vaadin.theme>
    <vaadin.plugin.version>${vaadin.version}</vaadin.plugin.version>
</properties>
```